# Bluetooth Mouse freezes for a 3-5 seconds after boot to desktop

Tags: udev, bluetooth

I am using pop os 20.04 which is basically Ubuntu derivate.

Since this version, I am experiencing issue with bluetooth mouse

When I start computer, after desktop is loaded (gnome), mouse will become unresponsive after 30seconds and I have to wait another 5seconds till it starts working again, as if somehow whole bluetooth stack got restarted.

I was exploring journalctl, and I have found out what will happen:

```
Jun 07 12:04:34 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Succeeded.
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: removing device Surface Mouse
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Option "fd" "64"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) event17 - Surface Mouse: device removed
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:81
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: removing device Surface Mouse Consumer Control
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Option "fd" "63"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:82, still in use
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: removing device Surface Mouse Consumer Control
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Option "fd" "63"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) event18 - Surface Mouse Consumer Control: device removed
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jun 07 12:04:39 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:44 pop-os bluetoothd[746]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os kernel: input: Surface Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0919.0005/input/input24
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os kernel: input: Surface Mouse Consumer Control as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0919.0005/input/input25
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os kernel: input: Surface Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0919.0005/input/input26
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os kernel: input: Surface Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0919.0005/input/input27
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os kernel: hid-generic 0005:045E:0919.0005: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.32 Mouse [Surface Mouse] on 80:91:33:f1:98:10
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Surface Mouse (/dev/input/mouse2)
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Surface Mouse (/dev/input/event19)
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Surface Mouse (/dev/input/event20)
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Surface Mouse Consumer Control (/dev/input/event18)
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Surface Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Surface Mouse Consumer Control'
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 63 paused 0
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Surface Mouse Consumer Control: always reports core events
Jun 07 12:04:45 pop-os /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
```

Basically after while, when desktop is loaded config/udev will remove bluetooth mouse and after while will re-add it again.

What is cause of this behavior and how to fix it?

Any help appreciated!